# More accurate search for string in a text

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex:

```
users_pattern = re.compile(r"\s- [a-zA-Z]+:")
```

The intention is to look in a text something like this:

```
- Nicolas:               -----> (space)- (one name):
```

But I just realized that I can have also the following statements in the text:

```
- ‪+1 (630) 854-8304‬:     -----> a number
- :                    -----> an emoji
- Mama Cel:              -----> 2 words
```

And I need to grab all of this.

Any idea on how can I fix my regex to grab all of this at once? Should I try to do this with another regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about any chars except "`:`"s?

```
r"^\s- [^:]+:"
```

If you're going to match against a multiline text, make sure you use the `re.MULTILINE` flag for `^` to match at the beggining of each line.

Check this [online](https://regex101.com/r/iH4hW9/1)

---

If you want to get the *key names* (without "`-`" and "`:`"), you can use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) by enclosing the part of the match you're interested in fetching in parens `(  pattern  )`. That way, `re.findall()` will not return the whole match. Instead, it will return what has been matched by that part of the pattern.

```
r"^\s- ([^:]+):"
```

**Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
p = re.compile( r'^\s- ([^:]+):', re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)
str = u" - Nicolas:               -----> (space)- (one name):\n - ‪+1 (630) 854-8304‬:     -----> a number\n - :                    -----> an emoji\n - Mama Cel:              -----> 2 words"
print re.findall(p, str)
```

Comment: Can i boder you with a minor detail?, just a quick questioin if i want to remove both ':' and '-' is it posible to add '^' to both in a regex?

Comment: @user3799942: using `([^:]+)` ... I added the info in the answer